# where is server log

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot, tomcat8

In a Spring boot project when I run the project on tomcat webserver it gives below exception.
This is part of stacktrace, in last line it says "See server log for details", but I can not find where server log is to look up for. I checked logs file (I mean this address: apache-tomcat-8.5.9\logs) and this path is empty.

NOTE: It was running successfully but I don't what changes make it not to run successfully anymore.

```
28-Mar-2017 16:25:35.336 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
28-Mar-2017 16:25:35.337 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
[2017-03-28 04:25:35,375] Artifact cardservice:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
```

Comment: As @luboskrnac said, it located inside of `catalina.out`. But, possibly, you launch tomcat using IDE, which create new tomcat instance inside of it, and in this case, tomcat log file will be somewhere in IDE directory. Also, in this case, you will be able to see logs inside of IDE. Also, possibly, you have many tomcat folders (instances) and you are launching tomcatA, and trying to search for logs in tomcatB. Once it happen with me.

Answer (score 3):

It will most probably be in Tomcat's log file called `catalina.out`.

Comment: Where is that file?

Comment: @user5621266 By default, that file should be in your Tomcat folder > logs, such as `~/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/logs/catalina.out`

Answer (score 0):

Probably under: `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.0\logs\catalina` something something if the installation directory is set at default.